# Merging two queries for pagination

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to get content of folder with pagination. Folder can contain documents and subfolders. So I have two JPQL queries:

```
SELECT f FROM Folder f WHERE f.parentFolder.id=:id; 
SELECT d from Folder f JOIN f.documentList d WHERE f.id=:id;
```

How can I "merge" this queries so i can use pagination? What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge these two queries into one single query as given below

```
select f, (SELECT d from Folder f JOIN f.documentList d WHERE f.id=id) FROM Folder f WHERE f.parentFolder.id=id;
```

This could be one simple way to do merge those query and capture the result back using an object created for the entity or you will be required to create a class which can hold all the records that will be returned using the query.

For Example:
If first select statement returns two fields like firstname and lastname and then the
second query returns 3 fields like age, phone, gender. Then you need to create a class which has 5 fields like firstname, lastname, age, phone and gender.